# Two zero sentences

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

**Zero then today we go**
**Zero disappears then Thursday appears**

*Ignore the rhymes, that's my guide, I won't resign!*

Comment: Is this referring to a specific date as in Lucas' answer, or could any day be "today"?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> March 31st. Today's date, a Thursday. Yesterday was the 30th, a 0 that has now disappeared.